# Unity cannot find classes inside AAR

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity game which uses an Android Library packed in an AAR (`library.aar`). However, I need to access the Main Activity's lifecycle callbacks (`onPause()`, `onResume()`, to name a few).

So I created a new library project in Android Studio (let's call this `plugin`). I imported `library.aar` into `plugin` and added it to the Dependencies. I tested it by calling the functions inside `library.aar` inside `MainActivity`. It doesn't throw any errors at this point.

In `MainActivity`, I called `Library.onActivityResult()`, `Library.onResume()`, and `Library.onPause()` in the respective functions.

Next, I added the `classes.jar` from `Unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/androidplayer/release/bin` into my `plugin` project. I added the JAR into the dependencies. I tested it by trying to subclass `UnityPlayerActivity`. Again, no errors yet.

I compile `plugin` into `plugin-debug.aar` and put it in `Assets/Plugins/Android`. I also created an `AndroidManifest.xml` which I got from [the Unity Manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html) and put it inside `Assets/Plugins`.

I call the functions from a button in a Unity scene like so:

```
AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.alxcyl.plugin.MainActivity");
jc.CallStatic("connect");

// "connect" is a static function in the Java class MainActivity containing 
// a short message like so:
// Log.d("My Plugin", "connect() was called");
```

I build the game and run it on my Android device. If I click the button, `MyPlugin.connect()` is properly called since it logs the message it's supposed to when clicked.

I think the lifecycle callbacks are properly called but the problem is that it logs an error saying:

```
I/dalvikvm( 5466): Could not find method com.somecompany.library.Library.onActivityResult, referenced from method com.alxcyl.plugin.MainActivity.onActivityResult
W/dalvikvm( 5466): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 276: Lcom/somecompany/library/Library;.onActivityResult (IILandroid/content/Intent;)V
I/dalvikvm( 5466): Could not find method com.somecompany.library.Library.onPause, referenced from method com.alxcyl.plugin.MainActivity.onPause
W/dalvikvm( 5466): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 276: Lcom/somecompany/library/Library;.onPause()V
I/dalvikvm( 5466): Could not find method com.somecompany.library.Library.onResume, referenced from method com.alxcyl.plugin.MainActivity.onResume
W/dalvikvm( 5466): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 276: Lcom/somecompany/library/Library;.onResume()V
D/MyPlugin( 5466): connect() was called
```

I'm not sure what causes it. When you build the `plugin` project, it builds fine without any errors but when you access it through Unity, it doesn't work. I tried to use the same `library.aar` into a new Android project and `Library.onActivityResult()`, `Library.onPause()`, and `Library.onResume()` definitely exists and are properly called.

Could it be that Unity can't handle AARs that include AARs? Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the .jar file with all your compiled code is missing in the .aar library.

Unity compiles its own .jar file with all .jar files from all plugins together, into one .dex file.

On Unity forums, you posted "class not found" error; here you mention "method not found". Anyway, something seems to be wrong with your .aar file.